# Discovering vulnerabilites in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

As I am developing an application. How I can find the vulnerabilities which give hackers a chance to attack? And what are the security mechanisms possible here?

For example this code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in USER_GROUP_FROMS.Rows)
{             
    var chkboxuser = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("mainsupp");

    abc = "";

    if (chkboxuser.Checked == true)
    {
        string xe = "DATA SOURCE=technovalms;USER ID=AMC; password=amc;";
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = xe;

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into TECHNOVA_SMS_USER_PRIVILEAGE(ID,SMS_USER_ID,SMS_PAGE_ID) values(SEQUENCEMODEL.nextval,'" + user_type.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + chkboxuser + "') ";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OWASP is your friend:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

There is a lot of information in the site, you can start with the [Web Application Security Testing Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Application_Security_Testing_Cheat_Sheet) for a good introduction to the subject and a checklist of tasks to be performed during security testing of a Web application.

**EDIT**

By the way, the code you have provided is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks.

You are appending the contents of your controls directly to your query so a user could input something like the following:

```
1';DELETE FROM TECHNOVA_SMS_USER_PRIVILEAGE'
```

Voila! They have access to all your database information.

To avoid this you should always filter user input using parameters:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into TECHNOVA_SMS_USER_PRIVILEAGE(ID,SMS_USER_ID,SMS_PAGE_ID) values(SEQUENCEMODEL.nextval,':selectedValue',':chkboxuser') ";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("selectedValue", user_type.SelectedValue.ToString()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("chkboxuser", chkboxuser));
```

Comment: OH... SO almost my system created by using my controls directly. what i can do in this case ?. i have already created many pages.

Comment: You need to use paremeters like in the example in my answer.